# Firebase Listener or Pull-To-Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an App which displays some information to the user. This information changes multiple times per day (sometimes multiple times per hour).

I'm using Firebase and setting listeners for this information.

1. Is it reliable to assume that these listeners **will always work**?
2. If the **app is not closed** (so the component is never unmounted), will the listeners ever expire/close?
3. Is implementing a pull-to-refresh a more reliable way to update information.

The situation I'm worried about is something happening with a listener and the only way the user can then update the app is by shutting it down and restarting to trigger new listeners.

Answer (score 0):

1. once the app is closed the listner wont work
2. no it ll keep listnening if the system have enough battery or the app is not closed by the system. [when app remains in background the app is disbaled by android system to save battery and when the user comes it restarts]
3. it depends upon the kind of application is. if the app is some stocks or chat kind of thing then data must stream in real time while if the app displays some posts by some other user like in twitter user profile then pull to refresh is ok

RECOMMEND: you should also make a retrial function to check the state of the listener if it goes of then retry [helpful where there is a network break] moreover you should also give a mechanism to the user to refresh as it imprves the UX ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the react component lifecycle before getting an answer to this, `listener will always be a part of some component and listener will be initialized when some component is initialized into the memory` and listener life is dependent on that component once that component is unmounted from the memory that specific listener will not be invoked so now the answer of your first question is.

1. Even the app is not closed and you are navigating between the different screens and you put your listener in some child component `and that component is unmounted from the memory your listener will not work`.

Now came to the second question which is almost answered in my first answer.

2. So as I said in the first answer Until that component unmounted from the memory, the listener will work unless you close the app or the operating system kills the app due to some reason `but as long as the component keeps mounted into the memory your listener will keep working`.
3. I believe adding a pull to refresh is more convenient in your case another option is that you can use a mixture of your change listener and focus listener of your navigation library, `When the user focuses on some screen then you can fetch newer data` and in that way always fresh data will be displayed `instead of manual refresh`.